# HTTP Token generation not working in Python requests

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

So I wrote this script in curl to generate a token

```
token=$(curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"identifier": "...", "password": "..."}' "$HOST:$PORT/login" | ggrep -Po '"token":"(\K[^"]+)')
```

which works fine. However with the simplicity of Python 3 I'd like to perform the same task using requests. As I understand running

```
import requests, json
http = '...'
head = {'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = { 'username' : '...', 'password' : '...' }
r = requests.post(http, data=json.dumps(data), headers=head, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

should return the same but I get the error

```
{"id":"3bca1f46-0577-40a9-8e09-7d68557ad88f","rafalError":"WrongJson","message":"DecodingFailure at .identifier: Attempt to decode value on failed cursor"}
```

with `r.status_code` returning 422.

Comment: In your curl incantation you're using `{"identifier": "...", "password": "..."}` but you're using `'username'` in the `requests` version in python instead of `"identifier"`.  Is that possibly the issue?

Comment: Ah of course for some reason this link: https://opengear.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003549186-How-do-I-authenticate-to-your-RESTful-API- used username and not identifier. Should I close the thread?